# D3 Object Constancy not working with key function. Enter and Update contain all elements every time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to implement object constancy. The concept is to update the DOM with text using progressive phrases within the text as data.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// We need a way to change the data to illustrate the update pattern.
// We use lyrics to do this.  Below is code for updating the data.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var data = [];

function lyricIterator(phrases) {

    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
        next: function(){

            if (nextIndex >= (phrases.length - 1)) {
                nextIndex = 0;
                debugger;
            } else {
                nextIndex = nextIndex + 1;
            }

            // console.log(phrases.slice(nextIndex - 1, nextIndex + 2));

            return phrases.slice(nextIndex - 1, nextIndex + 2);

        }
    }
}

var lyrics = [
    {i : 0, phrase : "Row, row, row your boat,"},
    {i : 1, phrase : "Gently down the stream."},
    {i : 2, phrase : "Merrily, merrily, merrily, merrily,"},
    {i : 3, phrase : "Life is but a dream."}
]

// Instantiate an iterator for our lyrics
var rrryb = lyricIterator(lyrics)

/////////////
// Set up
//////////////

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");

//////////////////////////
// Redraw the elements
/////////////////////////

function update() {

    data = rrryb.next()

    var phrases = svg.selectAll("phrases")
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.i; });

    console.log("Update")
    console.log(phrases)
    console.log("Enter")
    console.log(phrases.enter())
    console.log("Exit")
    console.log(phrases.exit())

    phrases.exit().remove();

    // UPDATE
    // Update old elements as needed.
    phrases.attr("class", "update");

    phrases.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "enter")
        .attr("dy", function(d, i) { return i * 32; })
        .attr("dx", ".35em");

    phrases.text(function(d) { return d.phrase; })

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Register the function to run at some interval
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

setInterval(function() {
    update()
}, 1500);
```

I get this as output to the console (enter and update with all the elements everytime):

[image]

And the output is just the text stacked on one another

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
var phrases = svg.selectAll("phrases")//there is no DOM as phrases it will return an empty selection always.
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.i; });
```

it should be this:

```
var phrases = svg.selectAll("text")//select all the text
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.i; });
```

Reason: This will return an empty selection **always** `svg.selectAll("phrases")` that is why its appending all the time.

In second case it will return a selection of text DOMs.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y34073p4/)

Comment: Spot on.  Thank you.